# vuejs development server compiler getting stuck at 49%

Tags: javascript, vue.js, compiler-errors

I have a Vue JS project which gets stuck at 49% or sometimes 62% when I run `npm run serve`. After it gets stuck, it never compiles and keeps at the same percentage for hours.

I have tried googling this issue so many times, but it doesn't seem that anyone else has this problem.

[image: Here's the screenshot of the terminal]

[image: And her's my package.json]

Please, can anybody tell me if it is due to a package, am I doing something wrong here.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it temporarily by running `NODE_ENV=production npm run serve`, it seems it only compiles on `production` environment. Although didn't find a proper solution for that.